# Custom Group By and place some records in one group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

please consider data:

```
 Id          Group            Value
 -----------------------------------
 1            1                10
 2            1                12
 3            1                10
 4            2                90
 5            2                10
 6            3                30
 7            4                12
 8            4                11
 9            5                10
 10           5                11
```

I want to do `Group By` on this data as `1,2,3` place in one group and `4,5` place in another group. How I can do this with `SQL Server`?

thanks

---

**Edit 1)**

I want this result:

```
Groups                              Count
-----------------------------------------
Group for 1,2,3                       6
Group for 4,5                         4
```

Comment: Also show us [what you tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: please see my Edit 1. I want group by based on `Group` column but I have criteria.I want `1,2,3` place in one group and `4,5` in another group

Comment: @Kerezo - Why `1, 2, 3 ` are grouped together whereas `4, 5` are grouped to a different group? what is the rule for this grouping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using `outer apply` so you will not duplicate your code to group

```
select
    C.Group_Name, count(*)
from Table1
    outer apply
    (
        select
            case
                when C.[Group] in (1, 2, 3) then 'Group for 1, 2, 3'
                when C.[Group] in (4, 5) then 'Group for 4, 5'
            end as Group_Name
    ) as C
group by C.Group_Name
```

you can also use subquery

```
select
    C.Group_Name, count(*)
from 
(
    select
        case
            when T.[Group] in (1, 2, 3) then 'Group for 1, 2, 3'
            when T.[Group] in (4, 5) then 'Group for 4, 5'
        end as Group_Name,
        T.Value,
        T.Id
    from Table1 as T
) as C
group by C.Group_Name
```

Comment: You shouldn't write the inner select this way. The OP is looking for a group concatenation not write `'Group for 1, 2, 3'`

Comment: Well so usual `for xml` concatenation will work. There're 2-3 question about how concatenate fields arrive on stackoverflow each day. I can see no rule for grouping (other than [Group] <= 3) here

Comment: Yes `for xml` will do it. But you have to show the OP how to do it this way or any other way not to write it down the way you did. The problem is his question isn't clear so that you can't tell how he wants to group by the results. Why `1, 2, 3` are grouped together whereas `4, 5` are grouped to a different group.

Comment: Sometimes you just need to group `1, 2, 3` without any rules. For that case writing `for xml` may be a bit overkill

Answer (score 3):

This may also do what you want:

```
SELECT 'Group for 1,2,3' AS GROUPS
   ,   COUNT(Id) AS Count
FROM Foo
WHERE [Group] IN (1,2,3)

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Group for 4,5' AS GROUPS
   ,   COUNT(Id) AS Count
FROM Foo
WHERE [Group] IN (4,5)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cdb82/2/0

Of course this works only if you know which groups you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I think a far simpler solution would be:

```sql
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN "Group" IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 'Group for 1, 2, 3'
    WHEN "Group" IN (4, 5) THEN 'Group for 4, 5'
      END AS "Groups",
  COUNT("Value") AS "Count"
FROM
  some_table
GROUP BY 1
```