# Group by multiple values in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

My data table looks like this:

```
client   Status
   1       a
   2       b
   3       a
   4       d
   5       d
   6       a
   7       e
   8       b
   9       e
  10       f
```

Say I want to group by the table by status, but instead, I want group status `a,b,d` (status `I`) as one group and `e,f` (status `II`) as another group

I want it looks like this eventually

```
status Count
   I      7
  II      3
```

How should I write the query?

Comment: My preference on these is to make a reference table that has entrees mapping a,b,d to status I and e,f to status II.   This answer here suggests using case.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269638/custom-group-by-and-place-some-records-in-one-group

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a CASE statement.

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN Status IN ('a', 'b', 'd')
    THEN 'I'
  WHEN Status IN ('e', 'f')
    THEN 'II'
  END AS "Status Group",
  count(*) as Count
FROM Table
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run the grouping and count into one statement.

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN Status IN ('a', 'b', 'd') THEN 'I' ELSE 'II' END AS Status,
  count(*) as count
FROM Table1
GROUP BY  (CASE WHEN Status IN ('a', 'b', 'd') THEN 'I' ELSE 'II' END)
ORDER BY Status

Result:
Status  count
 I      7
II      3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use group by with case

```
declare @table table ( client INT, STATUS Varchar(10))
insert into @table
select 1  , 'a' union all
select 2 ,  'b' union all
select 3  , 'a' union all
select 4  , 'd' union all
select 5  , 'd' union all
select 6  , 'a' union all
select 7  , 'e' union all
select 8  , 'b' union all
select 9  , 'e' union all
select 10 , 'f'
```

Query:

```
select clientgroup, count(*) Count from
(
select case when status in ( 'a','b','d') then 'I' else 'II' end clientgroup from @table 
) x group by clientgroup
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write the `CASE`-Statement twice, like jose_bacoy did. You can refer to the name you gave it in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clause.

```sql
SELECT
  CASE WHEN Status IN ('a', 'b', 'd') THEN 'I' ELSE 'II' END AS Status,
  count(*) as Count
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Status
ORDER BY Status
```