# Problems with SQL query with multiple values in "grouped by"

Tags: sql, bar-chart, metabase

I am using Matabase. I have the following tables: tms Taks, tms Sprint and tms TaskProjectRelationship and I want a query with this result in a bar chart where you can filter after the project to see which project has how many tasks commited or completed. It should look like this:

[image]

The Spints should be in the x-axix and the number of comited and completed tasks for each sprint should be in the y-axix

Tms Tasks has a column "Sprint" with a foreign key from the tms Sprint table. tms TaskProjectRelationship is a table where you have a column for the task id and a column for the project id next to it. With the editor I created a sql-query which looks like this:

```
SELECT "Tms Sprint - Sprint"."name" AS "Tms Sprint - Sprint__name", ("public"."tms_Task"."status"#>> '{detail}'::text[])::text  AS "status → detail", count(*) AS "count"
FROM "public"."tms_Task" INNER JOIN "public"."tms_Sprint" "Tms Sprint - Sprint" ON "public"."tms_Task"."sprint" = "Tms Sprint - Sprint"."id" INNER JOIN "public"."tms_TaskProjectRelationship" "Tms TaskProjectRelationship" ON "public"."tms_Task"."id" = "Tms TaskProjectRelationship"."task"
GROUP BY "Tms Sprint - Sprint__name", "status → detail"
ORDER BY "Tms Sprint - Sprint"."name" ASC, "status → detail" ASC
```

And I get this result:

[image]

But I want to have the status → detail grouped by multiple values like in the first picture where every "status -> detail" is "comited" and where the tasks with the "status -> detail" "closed" is "completed". I have seen this post [Group by multiple values in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49516715/group-by-multiple-values-in-one-column) but if I try it out I get problems with the syntax. How can I implement this and is it right to use a inner join in my query?